# Matlab - Filter Struct array using multiple strings

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have a large struct array

```
Month = 
1x10131 struct array with fields:
name
date
bytes
isdir
datenum
```

From which I need to filter a number of rows using an array (in the name field).

I was previously using

```
result = Month([string here])
```

But I just noticed that is not doing what I wanted at all, it seems to be filtering in someway, but not in anyway I desired.

I have the above struct array, and 4 strings (name) in a char array. I need an output of the four matched names with the associated date, bytes, isdir and datenum from the original array..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a little code snippet that will put in `SelectedMonth` the `struct`s that have the `name` field matching one of the entries in cell array `SelectedName`:

```
SelectedName  = {'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4'};  % change to your values
SelectedIndex = cellfun(@(x) any(strcmp(x, SelectedName)), {Month.name});
SelectedMonth = Month(SelectedIndex);
```

From here on you may extract wjhatever information you want from the struct array `SelectedMonth`. Please note that the string comparison is case sensitive, so be careful about the case of the names.